# How can I use generics to return a type who's sub-properties are the passed in types?

Tags: typescript

I'll start out with what I'm trying first.

I'm building out an sdk for an ordering API. The `order.get` method returns an order defined something like this (slimmed down for presentational purposes):

```js
interface Order {
    ID: string;
    Status: string;
    FromUser: User;
    Address: Address;
    xp: any;
}

interface User {
    ID: string;
    Username: string;
    xp: any;
}

interface Address {
    ID: string;
    City: string;
    xp: any;
}
```

Each object (Order, User and Address) has an xp field where users of the API can provide their own custom properties. For this reason xp is of type any. This is ok but we lose out on all the strongly-typed goodies. It would be really great if users could define a model for these xp values and pass them in when they call the method.

I *think* I can make it work by defining the method like this and passing in a type for each xp:

```js
public get<T, K, U>(orderID: string): Order<T, K, U> {
    // implementation details (return order object)
}
```

and then my interfaces would look something like this:

```js
interface Order<T = any, K = any, U = any> {
    ID: string;
    Status: string;
    FromUser: User<K>;
    Address: Address<U>;
    xp: T;
}

interface User<K = any> {
    ID: string;
    Username: string;
    xp: K;
}

interface Address<U = any> {
    ID: string;
    City: string;
    xp: U;
}
```

A couple of questions:

- Will this work? Am I using generic defaults correctly? The goal is that the user can pass in xp models for only the ones they want, even none at all.
- If this works it can still get tedious for a user to have to pass in three different types any time they want to call an order.get that returns a fully well defined type. Is there another way where they could pass through a single model that has the definitions for OrderXP, UserXp and AddressXP that somehow under the hood branch out to their respective fields

Comment: If you don't need to know anything about the `xp` stuff, why don't you just leave it up to the devs using your stuff to use the declaration merging features to add those properties into the interfaces and not worry about the genetics at all? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: Hey Daniel, just read the article and wow. It definitely seems to be a better solution than what I'm trying to hack together. THANK YOU!

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel How might a user of the sdk go about extending an interface defined by the SDK? All of these examples have merged interfaces in the same file? I tried importing the interface and then writing the addition below it but I get `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration`

Comment: Hmm also this makes me think its not going to work: `Non-function members of the interfaces should be unique. If they are not unique, they must be of the same type. The compiler will issue an error if the interfaces both declare a non-function member of the same name, but of different types.` My goal is to have a user define their own type for xp

Comment: They can be in separate files. Look at the Module Augmentation section. If you need to know about the `xp` property in your code then yeah this won't help (meaning that your library code actually uses that property... although I'm not sure how you would if you don't know anything about it's type at all and allow the `any` type)